# Нужна ли тут запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Иногда создается впечатление, что Дюма вообще боится работы и ищет способ, как бы ее избежать" - нужна ли запятая перед "как бы"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужна. Дюма ищет способ (какой?), как избежать. Запятая стоит перед придаточным определительным.